# Converting RGB image into 3 HSI outputs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, rgb

Im trying to convert a RGB image into HSI where it comes in three different outputs; Hue, saturation and intensity.

This is what I've done so far:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    //This line of code interts the picture of a cat 

    float r, g, b, h, s, in;

    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/pjusk/Desktop/kitti.jpg");

    if (image.data && !image.empty()) {
        imshow("Hello world!", image);

        Mat h1(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
        Mat s1(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());
        Mat i1(image.rows, image.cols, image.type());

        float r, g, b, h, s, in;

        for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
            {
                b = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
                g = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
                r = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];

                in = (b + g + r) / 3;

                float min_val = 0;
                min_val = std::min(r, std::min(b, g));

                s = 1 - 3 * (min_val / (b + g + r));
                if (s < 0.00001)
                {
                    s = 0;
                }
                else if (s > 0.99999) {
                    s = 1;
                }

                if (s != 0)
                {
                    h = 0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b)) / sqrt(((r - g)*(r - g)) + ((r - b)*(g - b)));
                    h = acos(h);

                    if (b <= g)
                    {
                        h = h;
                    }
                    else {
                        h = ((360 * 3.14159265) / 180.0) - h;
                    }
                }


                h1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
                h1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = s * 100;
                h1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = in;

                s1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
                s1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = s * 100;
                s1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = in;

                i1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
                i1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = s * 100;
                i1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = in;
            }
        }


        imshow("h1 image", h1);
        imshow("s1 image", s1);
        imshow("i1 image", i1);


        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out!
For now the output is 4 images, the RGB one and three HSI images, that is apparently not split up into the H, S and I value as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The usual terminology is *channels*. An RGB image has 3 channels, Red, Green and Blue (actually B,G,R as you correctly noted). And an HSI image *also* has 3 channels, but different channels. But you're not creating one HSI image with 3 channels, you're creating 3 images with 3 channels. They're obviously identical.

And how would `imshow(i1)` know that those 3 channels are supposed to form an HSI image? Numbers are just numbers, and RGB or HSI are interpretations given to numbers. `imshow` will display the first channel (H) as blue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've to modify the following:

```
//The h, s and i images should be of type CV_8UC1
Mat h1(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat s1(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat i1(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);

//Since h1 is a one channel image, s and l should not be added
h1.at<uchar>(i, j) = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
//h1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = s * 100;
//h1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = in;

//Since s1 is a one channel image, h and l should not be added
//s1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
s1.at<uchar>(i, j) = s * 100;
//s1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = in;

//Since i1 is a one channel image, h and s should not be added
//i1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = (h * 180) / 3.14159265;
//i1.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = s * 100;
i1.at<uchar>(i, j) = in;
```